# How to hide post after sometime?

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is the detail of question. I've column in database named ( time_show ) it's time for select when the post is hide , so after this time the post should be hidden , I been try this func js but it's not worked ...

For example of idea : I want to hide post after 10 min ...

Image for column >> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgFUp.png)

Code :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {            

        let time = "{{ $question_one->time_show }}";
        setTimeout(function(){ 

            $('.hide-question').hide();
            $('.show-alert').show();

         }, time*60*1000);

    });
```

How can I do something like that ?

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the time first to unix timestamp.

```
$(document).ready(function() {            

        let time = "{{ $question_one->time_show }}";

        let time_unix  = new Date(time).getTime();

        let now = new Date().getTime();

        if(now<time_unix) {

            setTimeout(function(){ 

                $('.hide-question').hide();
                $('.show-alert').show();

             }, time_unix - now);
        } else {
                $('.hide-question').hide();
                $('.show-alert').show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: And then  sir , hasan??

Comment: Try this one only.

Comment: The let me know, what will be the 'time_show value'? **hh:mm:ss** ?

Comment: this : 2019-06-17 23:47:35

Comment: after convert the time to unix timestamp , now it's :2019-06-17 23:47:35

Comment: still not working :( , i the post doesn't hide after the time :( 
I said in this time ( 2019-06-18 14:38:46 ) hide but still show up !

Comment: Oh, sorry, actually i made a mistake. now solved that issue. try now.

Comment: yes man , it's works :) .... thank you so much , I owe you :) 
can you give me your email if you don't mind :)

Comment: hasan.mediusware@gmail.com